# Should we get syntax highlighting?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

We can already add blocks of code:

```
def foo:
    return bar
```

But the code is not syntax-highlighted, i.e., keywords a certain color, etc. ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56450798/python-inner-functions-decorators-when-should-i-use-parentheses-when-returning).) My understanding is that this is an option that Stack Exchange has to turn on, and that sites need to ask for it.

**Should we ask for syntax highlighting?**

Also, there are packages out there that provide [syntax highlighting for AMPL](https://github.com/JackDunnNZ/sublime-ampl), and I'm sure GAMS and other modeling languages too. (I haven't checked for those.) But these are not part of the tool that SE uses for syntax highlighting (more [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/504785)). OTOH that tool seems to be open source, so if anyone has expertise in this area and wants to try to get some modeling languages added, have at it.

Comment: I think it would be a nice addition and beneficial for readibility of code snippets. Highlighting for GAMS and friends would be nice to have as well.

Comment: Are there any downsides to adding syntax highlighting? Significantly slower page loads? Something like that?

Comment: @DavidM. I don't think there is much overhead for syntax highlighting. Much less than MathJax rendering, at the least.